# SAS insert date format

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I have the following codes:

```
PROC SQL;

    CREATE TABLE Hub_Category2 (
    CategoryID INT NOT NULL,
    CategoryName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    LOAD_DATE NUM FORMAT=DATETIME22. NOT NULL,
    RECORD_SOURCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
RUN;

quit;

%let "LOAD_DATE: %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime22.)"; 

%let RECORD_SOURCE='123'; 

proc sql;

    CREATE VIEW VIEW_HUB_CATEGORIES AS
    SELECT 
    CategoryID,
    CategoryName,
    &LOAD_DATE as LOAD_DATE, 
    &RECORD_SOURCE as RECORD_SOURCE 
    FROM  LIB.CATEGORIES;
RUN;
Quit;
```

When I run the following code

```
proc sql;

  insert into Hub_Category2 select * from VIEW_HUB_CATEGORIES;

  run;

Quit;
```

It is giving the following error.

```
proc sql;
    72         insert into Hub_Category2 select * from VIEW_HUB_CATEGORIES;
 ERROR: Value 3 on the SELECT clause does not match the data type of the 
corresponding column listed after the INSERT table name.
```

I think, I made mistake while formatting date, inserting or using macro. Please, help me

Comment: Your first `%let` statement is not valid SAS code since it does not include the macro variable name that you want to assign a value into.  What code did you actually run?

Comment: Why would you put a constant datetime value into a view?  Are you trying to record when the view was created?  If you want to execute the `datetime()` function when you pull data using the view then code the actual function call into the view definition instead of a constant value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro variable `LOAD_DATE` is either not present, or incorrectly valued with respect to source code generation.

Try

```
%let LOAD_DATE = %sysfunc(datetime());  %* macro variable value is source code (a bunch of digits) representing current datetime;
%let RECORD_SOURCE = '123';             %* macro variable value is source code for a single quoted string literal;

proc sql;
    CREATE VIEW VIEW_HUB_CATEGORIES AS
    SELECT 
    CategoryID,
    CategoryName,
    &LOAD_DATE as LOAD_DATE, 
    &RECORD_SOURCE as RECORD_SOURCE 
    FROM  LIB.CATEGORIES;
RUN;
```

The value being placed in the `LOAD_DATE` column at

```
&LOAD_DATE as LOAD_DATE
```

does not need to be formatted for human readability, it needs to be the date time value itself.